# New users all get error on activation attempt

Tags: activation

Every time I set up a new user user and send the activation link. The user gets the following error when trying to activate their account:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> Undefined Index: action

The only way to fix it has been to turn on and off the permissions multiple times until it works. Can anyone help fix this problem?

**htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

## BEGIN Enable GZIP Compression ##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>
## END Enable GZIP Compression ##


## BEGIN Vary: Accept-Encoding Header ##
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
## END Vary: Accept-Encoding Header ##


# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
PHP notice

Undefined index: action

/var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/plugins/limitblocktype/LimitBlockTypePlugin.php(50)

38         }
39 
40         $isAjaxRequest = craft()->request->isAjaxRequest();
41         $segments = craft()->request->segments;
42         $actionSegment = array_pop($segments) ?: '';
43 
44         if (!$isAjaxRequest) {
45             
46             craft()->templates->includeJsResource('limitblocktype/js/limitblocktype.js');
47             
48             // Check request parameters
49             $vars = craft()->request->getPost();
50             if (!empty($vars) && $vars['action'] === 'fields/saveField' && $vars['type'] === 'Matrix') {
51                 // This is so hacky I don't even
52                 craft()->runController('limitBlockType/saveField');
53             }
54 
55         }
56 
57         if (!$isAjaxRequest || $actionSegment === 'getEditorHtml') {
58             $data = JsonHelper::encode(craft()->limitBlockType->getData());
59             craft()->templates->includeJs('if (Craft && Craft.LimitBlockTypePlugin) { new Craft.LimitBlockTypePlugin('.$data.', '.($isAjaxRequest ? '1' : '0').'); }');
60         }
61 
62     }
Stack Trace
#0  
–  /var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(687): CApplication->handleError(8, "Undefined index: action", "/var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/plugins/limit...", 50)
682         if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7', '>=') && $code === 2 && strpos($message, 'should be compatible with') !== false)
683         {
684             return;
685         }
686 
687         parent::handleError($code, $message, $file, $line);
688     }
689 
690     // Private Methods
691     // =========================================================================
692 
#1  
–  /var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/plugins/limitblocktype/LimitBlockTypePlugin.php(50): Craft\WebApp->handleError(8, "Undefined index: action", "/var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/plugins/limit...", 50, ...)
45             
46             craft()->templates->includeJsResource('limitblocktype/js/limitblocktype.js');
47             
48             // Check request parameters
49             $vars = craft()->request->getPost();
50             if (!empty($vars) && $vars['action'] === 'fields/saveField' && $vars['type'] === 'Matrix') {
51                 // This is so hacky I don't even
52                 craft()->runController('limitBlockType/saveField');
53             }
54 
55         }
#2  
–  /var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/app/services/PluginsService.php(150): Craft\LimitBlockTypePlugin->init()
145                     $this->_enabledPlugins[$row['lcHandle']]->setSettings($row['settings']);
146                 }
147 
148                 foreach ($this->_enabledPlugins as $plugin)
149                 {
150                     $plugin->init();
151                 }
152 
153                 $this->_loadingPlugins = false;
154             }
155 
#3  
+  /var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(257): Craft\PluginsService->loadPlugins()
#4  
+  /var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#5  
+  /var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#6  
+  /var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/public/index.php(26): require_once("/var/www/vhosts/aura.ecwebhub.co.uk/httpdocs/craft/app/index.php")
2017-08-08 21:13:32 Apache / Craft CMS 2.6.2988
```

Comment: Have you changed the `actionTrigger` value in a config file? Which version of Craft are you on?

Comment: Also, can you edit the original question to share your `.htaccess` file as well?

Comment: no the actionTrigger hasn't been changed and am on the most up to date version of Craft 2

Comment: Any chance you could reproduce the issue with devMode enabled and share the full stack trace leading up to that error?

Comment: Not currently as I can only access it from work unfortunately.

Comment: Has anything changed about being able to enable devMode and get a full stack trace for that error?

Comment: I can enable mode. How do I show the full stack trace?

Comment: Have added full stack trace above. Highlighted line is `if (!empty($vars) && $vars['action'] === 'fields/saveField' && $vars['type'] === 'Matrix') {` from LimitBlockTypePlugin.php

Comment: So if you disable this plugin the activation should work. It seems they expect an action key in the $vars variable that is not always there.

Comment: That seems to be the issue. LimitBlockTypePlugin was interfering with the password setup. Thanks Brad Bell and kant312. This has been causing me problems for months